# Compare a json with nested elements after it has been modifed

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring, json-patch

I have a usecase where I want to figure out how a json was modified. I have to compare 2 json objects, one before it was modifed and one object representing the state after modfication. The json have many nested objects and arrays in it.
The json comparison can be done through [RFC 6902](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6902) and [RFC 7396](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7396) which has standard implementations.

The JSON is actually a Java object which has many properties and references to other objects. This causes 2 problems. If the reference id of any child object is updated it would mean the whole object has been replaced rather than just the id field. The other is ordering of objects in collections. I would try to explain the 2 scenarios:

Lets say the `id` of a child object (car in this case) is modified like below

```
// initial state
{
  "employee": {
    "id": 1,
    "car": {
      "id": 11,
      "field1": "foo"
    }
  }
}
// modified state
{
  "employee": {
    "id": 1,
    "car": {
      "id": 12,
      "field1": "foo"
    }
  }
}
```

Then the JSON patch would return
`{"employee":{"car":{"id":12}}}`
or
`[{"op":"replace","path":"/employee/car/id","value":12}]`
indicating the `id` was updated. But in my usecase it would mean the existing child object `car` with id 11 was removed and a new object car with id 12 was placed in its place.

The second problem is in case of collections, the order should not matter. So, the below 2 json comparison would return that the object was not modified.

```
{
  "employee": {
    "id": 1,
    "cars": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "field1": "foo"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "field1": "bar"
      }
    ]
  }
}
// modified json
{
  "employee": {
    "id": 1,
    "cars": [
      {
        "id": 12,
        "field1": "bar"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "field1": "foo"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But according to the RFC's the order of the collection matter and changing the index of an item would return an update. For the above change the patch would return
`{"employee":{"cars":[{"id":12,"field1":"bar"},{"id":11,"field1":"foo"}]}}`
or

```
[{"op":"replace","path":"/employee/cars/1/id","value":11},
{"op":"replace","path":"/employee/cars/1/field1","value":"foo"},
{"op":"replace","path":"/employee/cars/0/id","value":12},
{"op":"replace","path":"/employee/cars/0/field1","value":"bar"}]
```

I can probably write custom code for these two scenarios but I wanted to understand if any json patch implementation (java) can be handle these 2 cases or if there is some library which can support this. Or if someone has an idea how to best approach the problems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For your first problem: Any comparison can only point out the differences. How you deal with those differences is up to you. If something was modified or replaced with something new is a semantic issue that cannot be decided automatically.

Comment: @derpirscher I agree with you. If the differences are on any field other than the `id` it means the object was modified but if the `id` changes it would mean a new object is created with the fields and the old one is removed. This is a deeply nested json which represents a java class with a large number of nested references and object creation/removal would have its own flows. I am trying to figure out what would be a good approach to handle this problem

Comment: What you are asking for can't be done via String comparison. As you said, order matters here.  For instance, consider a diff tool.  Any diff tool, such as Beyond Compare, will only compare each line of a string with its corresponding line of a different string (with some capabilities to determine new lines).  If you want to determine the difference in these deeply nested structures, you will need to deserialize the json into an object and compare the resulting object fields.